# Regular Expression with a NOT match

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate file names for further processing.

I want to match a file with extension `.txt`, `.csv`, or `.log`
 but I want to exclude them if it ENDS with `_out.csv` or `mylog.log`

Here is my start:

```
    Function CanProcessFile(strFileNameIn, strLogName, strOutName)
      Dim objRegEx, colMatches, strPattern
      Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      strPattern = "((.txt$)|(.csv$)|(.Log$))"
      strPattern = "(?!(" & strLogName & "$))" & strPattern
      'strPattern = "(?!(" & strOutName & "$))" & strPattern
      objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
      objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
      Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strFileNameIn)
      If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        CanProcessFile = True
      Else
        CanProcessFile = False
      End If
    End Function
```

but every time I try to add a `^` or `?!` with `(_out.csv$)` it fails.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if I should just create two expressions and if it matches the first filter, then reject if it matches the second expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that creating two filters (as you suggest in a comment above) may well be the best way to go, but if you prefer to do it in a single regex, then you should be able to write:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "^(?!.*(_out\.csv|mylog\.log)$).*\.(txt|csv|log)$"
```

which ensures that the file doesn't *start* with `.*(_out\.csv|mylog\.log)$` (i.e., that it doesn't *end* with `_out.csv` or `mylog.log`).

Comment: This works as coded, however it requires that the out file and log file must be hardcoded.  Which I was trying to avoid by appending simple initial user declarations in the beginning of the VBS. unless there is some way to not require the "." to be hashed, other than another RegEx.Replace.... But then again, what is the likelihood of an extension-less "mylog_log" file existing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if vbscript supports negative lookbehind, but if it does, have a try with:

```
(?<!_out|mylog)\.(?:txt|csv|log)$
```

May be vbscript accepts negative lookbehind but not variable length lookbehind, in that case, use:

```
(?<!_out)(?<!mylog)\.(?:txt|csv|log)$
```

Comment: @PaulYoung: may be vbscript doesn't accept variable length lookbehind. See my edit.

Comment: Nope, both produce a "Syntax error in regular expression" at character: 3

Comment: @PaulYoung: Then I'm afraid that vbscript doesn't support lookbehind. As you said in comment, create two regex.